# What are the 7 treasures that are delivered by Soma-Rudra in Rig Veda 6.74.1

Tags: shiva, rudra

Hello experts: I am using the translation of Elizarenkova ( Russian Translator ) for Rig Veda 6.74.1. Please share what are the 7 treasures delivered to all homes by Soma and Rudra?

*"O Soma-Rudra, keep (your) asura power, May our desires reach you in time! Bringing seven treasures to each house, Be for the good of (our) two-legged, (our) four-legged!"*

This translation is consistent with Geldner and others. Is there a relation to these 7 gems/treasures in other hymns or other Vedic Shakas? Please share. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number 7 has a significance important to the seers of the Rig Veda.

Rig Veda mentions:

Sapta Rishis (Seven ages; also in the sky as Ursa Major constellation)

Sapta Sindhu (Seven Rivers in Punjab)

Seven horses of sun

Seven mouths of Brihaspati

Seven priests at the sacrifice

Seven holy places

Seven castles of the aerial demons destroyed by indra

Seven holy singers

Seven rays of sun

Seven tongues/ flames of Agni (Fire)

Seven male children

Seven elements

Seven Adityas

Seven foundations of the sea

Seven races of men

Seven heads, 7 hands, 7 tongues

Seven threads

Seven germs within the seed

Seven meters

Seven tones

Sapta Vadhri

(This list is taken from The Rig Veda – A Historical Analysis by Shrikant G Talageri)

[Refer here](https://www.speakingtree.in/blog/number-7-rig-vedic-link-to-indus-valley-culture#:%7E:text=Number%20seven%20is%20used%20in%20Indus%20valley%20civilisation,in%20Music%21%20%28posted%20on%2013%20th%20April%202013%29)

> Sanskrit text [Accents, Plain, Transliterated]: सोमा॑रुद्रा
> धा॒रये॑थामसु॒र्यं१॒॑ प्र वा॑मि॒ष्टयोऽर॑मश्नुवन्तु । दमे॑दमे स॒प्त
> रत्ना॒ दधा॑ना॒ शं नो॑ भूतं द्वि॒पदे॒ शं चतु॑ष्पदे ॥ सोमारुद्रा
> धारयेथामसुर्यं प्र वामिष्टयोऽरमश्नुवन्तु । दमेदमे **सप्त रत्ना दधाना** शं
> नो भूतं द्विपदे शं चतुष्पदे ॥ somārudrā dhārayethām asuryam pra vām
> iṣṭayo 'ram aśnuvantu | dame-dame **sapta ratnā dadhānā** śaṃ no bhūtaṃ
> dvipade śaṃ catuṣpade ||
>
> English translation: “Soma and Rudra, confirm (in us the strength) of
> asuras may sacrifices in every dwelling adequately reach you; do you,
> possessors of the seven precious things, bestow happiness upon us;
> happiness upon our bipeds and quadrupeds.”

[Let us refer to Sāyaṇa's Ṛgveda-bhāṣya](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/rig-veda-english-translation/d/doc834495.html)

> Possessors of seven precious things: sapta ratnā dadhāna; perhaps a
> reference to seven dhātus or seven elements

[Refer to the Seven dhātus here](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/dhatu#hinduism)

Comment: Thank you SaffronVajra. But which one should one pick the Ayurvedic Dhatu of the physical body or the wisdom of the seven rishis. Is there a relation or reference to this in later mandalas or other Vedic Shakas?

Comment: @SanatanaDhara I'm not knowledgeable in this regard, I can only point you in a direction, sorry for not being of help. 

But I will keep an eye on this. Maybe ask a few people around.

Comment: thank you for the help and honesty. It was valuable info. I will wait for a few more responses.